# Overheating Chevy

Tags: chevrolet, overheating, cruze

I have a 2011 Chevy Cruze 1.4 T manual that I purchased March 2016. About 1.5 - 2 months ago my car started overheating. The h20 pump and thermostat were replaced a year and a half ago. I've also had 2 vacuum leaks in 2 years, not sure if that's relatable. I had taken the car to Firestone and they said I needed the thermostat assembly. Was going to be pricey. I drive Uber. I let the car sit a day, then I had to work to make money to fix this #@$+&!* car, so I just worked Uber eats. I would never let the car run idle, I shut it off at lights, etc. For a couple days the fan did stay running while the car was on, then I noticed it stopped. Then a couple days later I noticed the CEL was off. The car ran fine for going on 2 months. It never overheated again. I had not been running the air, but a few times it got super hot and I ran it for a few minutes, but nothing happened. Last night, it started all over again.. I ordered the part, I have a mechanic friend who said it's easy and will help me out and install it for me. However, I'm not convinced it was properly checked out and that's the actual problem. Fingers crossed it is. 
Does anyone know WHY it would just stop overheating for so long? And then start again? I thought maybe a plastic bag got lodged somewhere because I didn't think a check engine light just goes off. It was like it corrected itself. 
And before someone reprimands me for driving it, I know it's damaging.. Unfortunately I had no choice. The times the needle did creep or hit the hot zone, I pulled over and shut it down.

Appreciate any input

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! The thermostat seems like a reasonable issue you might be having. The reason I say that is, the thermostat is the only part I'm aware of in the cooling system which *might* be intermittent. It could possibly stop working for a period of time, then work, then stop again. Most everything else, like low coolant, head gasket leak, water pump failure, fan relay or fan, radiator clog, (what have you) will keep causing issues and won't mysteriously heal itself. The thermostat, being a thermo-mechanical device just might. Long shot, but seems reasonable.

Comment: What was the code? Was the car actually overheating? Or did it just think it was? No loss of coolant?